# splitting a string into different arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

**My input format**
 the number of types of items, followed by N (N - no.of items) lines each representing a pair of integers in the format L B where L is the length of the item and B is the breadth of the item.

**Sample input format:**
2
1 1
5 4

**My question is how send all lengths into one array and all breadths into one array with out using vectors in C++. I know these kind of questions were already asked by people but I couldn't figure out how to send them to two different arrays.**

my program should run in a sandbox. Sandbox automatically gives input to the program. So I have to write my program in a way that takes the above input format

Comment: I have not understood what these numbers 2 1 1 5 4 mean.

Comment: Would help to know how you get that input. Is it a txt file?

Comment: Its not a text file. my program should run in a sandbox. Sandbox automatically gives input to the program. So I have to write my program in a way that takes the above input format

Answer (score 1):

```
cin >> n;
int *l,*b;
l = new int[n];
b = new int[n];

for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
  cin >> l[i] >> b[i];
}
```

Comment: I will enter the whole string 1 1 at a time with a space in the middle. Do I not need to split the string by space

Comment: Yes, a space is needed to seperate the two integers. Also you can enter your numbers with any number of spaces or newlines, just the order matters.

Comment: The length of the array has to be a constant known at compile time, so you can't declare them like that.  Use `std::vector<int> l(n), b(n)`. Since vectors return references, the subsequent lines in the loop will still work.

Comment: @HeywoodFloyd Can you tell me other way without vectors. Thanks

Comment: [user3005614](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3005614/user3005614), the edited code above will do it.  However, you'll need to free up the l and b arrays when you're done with them, or you'll have a memory leak.